# Mongo db $push operator not working

Tags: html, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push data in array in object in mongo model
 by using  **req.params** method
 but it is giving me 
ERROR:

**MongoError: cannot use the part (friends of friends.username) to traverse the element ( { friends:[ ] } )**

*Here's my Code:*

**BackEnd**

```
  router.post('/accept/:id/:username',isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
              User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.user.username,'friendRequest._id':req.params.id},
              {$set:{'friendRequest.$.Status':'Friend','friendRequest.$.Color':'green'}},function(err,founduser){

                if (err) {
                  throw err;
                } else {

               User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.user.username},
               {$push:{'friends.username':req.params.username}}
               ,function(err,founduser){

                 if (err) {
                  throw err;
                } else {

//Error is coming from this line
                User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.params.username},
                {$push:{'friends.username':req.user.username}}
                ,function(err,founduser){

                     if (err) {
                      throw err;
                    } else {
                        res.render("back");
                    }
                   })  
                }
                   }) 
                }   
              })  
            })


**My Model**


            var  mongoose = require('mongoose');
            var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

            var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

            username:String,
            password :String,

              friends:[{    
            username: String  //Here I wanna insert a data
            }],
```

**Front End**

```
<form  action = "/accept/<%=request._id%>/<%=request.username%>" method = "post"> 
         <button id="add" class="ui  medium  <%=request.Color%> button"><%=request.Status%></button> 
         </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a small change need to be made:

```
       User.findOneAndUpdate({
                username: req.params.username
            }, {
                $push: {
                    "friends":{
                           username:req.params.username
                     }                       
                }
            },function(err,founduser){
                 if (err) {
                  throw err;
                } else {
                    res.render("back");
                }})
```